# C/C++ golfing: Should undefined behaviour be allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609123/code-golf-take-2-inputs-number-and-print-sum-in-c) on SO raised some comments about using undefined behaviour in C/C++ golfing. Should we require that solutions follow the standard? If we do, we could promote down-voting of solutions relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm torn. One the one hand, all's fair in love and code golf. On the other, I don't think it's right to exploit gratuitous compiler behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I expect people relying on unspecified, undefined, or compiler specific behavior to *say so*. Then, if I think it is gratuitous I just won't vote for their answer.

Comment: If this is so, we need to specify it in the faq.

Comment: Also, the undefined behaviour cannot be used as a backdoor to compromise people's computers. See [this post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143/how-to-avoid-executing-malicious-obfuscated-code) for a discussion.

Comment: I like this solution. Why ban people from submitting solutions completely? If the community thinks a solution crosses a line in somewhat then they won't upvote it.